# React Native not opening firebase CAPTHCA

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I have a **React Native** app with *rnfirebase*. Sometimes firebase needs to launch the capcha in another window but my Android app is blocking it. It makes as it will open a new tab and chashes. I have tested it on IOS and works like a charm.

I also have a `Linking.openURL('google.com')` method in another part of the project and works perfectly.

Is there any permission I have to give to Android?

Versions: RN: 6.2.0, react-native-firebase: 13.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and was way more easy than what I was expecting. The problem was in the package name. I change my app package name but not the one of the Firebase Android App and both package name have to match.